# Integration problem solving without contour integration

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, self-learning, contour-integration

Can the following question be solved without using contour integration.

$F:(0,\infty)\times (0,\infty)\to \Bbb R$ be given by

$F(\alpha,\beta)=\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\frac{\cos(\alpha x)}{x^4+\beta^4}\,dx$

Show that

$\frac{F(\alpha,\beta)}{F(\beta,\alpha)}=\frac{\alpha^3}{\beta^3}$ as long as there is no positive integer **n** such that $\alpha=\frac{(4n-1)\pi\sqrt{2}}{4\beta}$

Comment: I gave it a few tries, but I am not able to solve it by Feynman integration. Integrating by power series also seems unlikely to succeed. And obviously finding an anti-derivative is completely hopeless as it is not elementary.

Comment: @SmileyCraft. In fact, there is an explicit formula for the integral.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Yeah, but do you know of a way of finding it without contour integration? And all I said was there is no explicit formula for the antiderivative of the integrand.

Comment: @SmileyCraft. A CAS made it for me (the integral) ! The antiderivative is quite awful but doable in terms of sine and cosine integrals after partial fracion decomposition.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I meant that it is not elementary. But indeed there is an antiderivative, but there always is one for continuous functions. By the way, what is a CAS?

Comment: @SmileyCraft. **C**omputer **A**lgebra **S**ystem

Comment: Not a complete answer because it partially relies on contour integral, but if you look at this (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3049850/how-to-simplify-the-result-i-obtain-for-the-following-integral-int-0-infty) question, you'll find your answer. If the condition you state is satisfied for an integer $n$, the problem is that your integral is $\propto \sin(\pi n)=0$, which means that your integral is equal to zero for all values of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ satisfying the condition. Your equality is then no longer valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question concerning why the quotient
$$\frac{F(\alpha, \beta)}{F(\beta, \alpha)} = \frac{\alpha^3}{\beta^3},$$
is only defined provided
$$\alpha \neq \frac{(4n - 1) \pi \sqrt{2}}{4b},$$
where $n \in \mathbb{N}$, it is helpful if one has the explicit expression for $F$ at hand.

Using the Residue Theorem a value for $F(\alpha, \beta)$ can be found. It is given by (for a proof of this, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3049850/how-to-simplify-the-result-i-obtain-for-the-following-integral-int-0-infty/3049903#3049903))
$$F (\alpha, \beta) = \frac{\pi}{2 \alpha^3} \exp \left (-\frac{\alpha \beta}{\sqrt{2}} \right ) \sin \left (\frac{\alpha \beta}{\sqrt{2}} + \frac{\pi}{4} \right ), \qquad \alpha, \beta > 0.$$
Similarly,
$$F (\beta, \alpha) = \frac{\pi}{2 \beta^3} \exp \left (-\frac{\alpha \beta}{\sqrt{2}} \right ) \sin \left (\frac{\alpha \beta}{\sqrt{2}} + \frac{\pi}{4} \right ), \qquad \alpha, \beta > 0.$$

If the required quotient is to be defined, clearly $F (\beta, \alpha) \neq 0$. Thus the sine term appearing in the expression for $F(\beta, \alpha)$ must be non-zero. Thus
$$\frac{\alpha \beta}{\sqrt{2}} + \frac{\pi}{4} \neq n \pi \quad \text{or} \quad \alpha \neq \frac{(4n - 1) \pi \sqrt{2}}{4 \beta},$$
where $n \in \mathbb{N}$, as required.

Answer (score 5):

Switching to integration parameter $t=\frac{\alpha}{\beta}x$ gives $$F(\alpha,\beta)=\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\frac{\cos(\beta t)}{(\frac{\beta}{\alpha}t)^4+\beta^4}\,\frac{\beta}{\alpha}\,dt=\frac{\alpha^3}{\beta^3}F(\beta,\alpha)$$

Comment: ,what about the condition of positive integer **n**?

Comment: As mentioned by Zachary, for such a special $\bf{n}$ one has $F(\alpha,\beta)=F(\beta,\alpha)=0$, so their quotient is undefined. Rewriting the equation as ${\beta}^3F(\alpha,\beta)={\alpha}^3F(\beta,\alpha)$ avoids that problem.